# Telegram Bot doesn't respond messages

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

i use server on Debian 8 with ISP 5. I have installed that lib: https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot. Webhook was set but bot doesn't respond messages and commands. Server hadn't logs, I do not know what the problem is :(

I received a SSL from Let's Encrypt in ISP Manager for IP adress.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soOxw.png)

Here is my set.php

```
<?php
// Load composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$API_KEY = 'key';
$BOT_NAME = 'evtepo_bot';
$hook_url = 'https://213./hook.php';
try {
    // Create Telegram API object
    $telegram = new Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram($API_KEY, $BOT_NAME);

    // Set webhook
    $result = $telegram->setWebhook($hook_url);
    if ($result->isOk()) {
        echo $result->getDescription();
    }

} catch (Longman\TelegramBot\Exception\TelegramException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

And hook.php

```
<?php
// Load composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$API_KEY = 'key';
$BOT_NAME = 'evtepo_bot';
$commands_path = __DIR__ . '/Commands/';

try {
    // Create Telegram API object
    $telegram = new Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram($API_KEY, $BOT_NAME);

    // Handle telegram webhook request
    $telegram->handle();
} catch (Longman\TelegramBot\Exception\TelegramException $e) {
     echo $e;
     \Longman\TelegramBot\TelegramLog::initErrorLog(__DIR__ . '/' . $BOT_NAME . '_error.log');
     \Longman\TelegramBot\TelegramLog::initDebugLog(__DIR__ . '/' . $BOT_NAME . '_debug.log');
     \Longman\TelegramBot\TelegramLog::initUpdateLog(__DIR__ . '/' . $BOT_NAME . '_update.log');
}

$telegram->addCommandsPath($commands_path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to buy a domain and get a SSL from Lets'Encrypt.

Comment: Did you setup webhook with Lets Encrypt cert? I am trying to switch from my self-signed cert to a Lets Encrypt cert but Telegram fails at validating the new cert.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getwebhookinfo) method to check if the updates were delivered to the hook and if there were any errors.